# How to do that Mongodb aggregation in golang

Tags: mongodb, go, pipe, aggregate, mgo

I have a MongoDB collection like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a017ee061313781045889ea"),  "device_id" : "1232213",   "value" : "23233", "pubtime" : ISODate("2017-11-07T09:37:37.006Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a017f7b61313781045889eb"),  "device_id" : "1111",   "value" : "23233", "pubtime" : ISODate("2017-11-07T09:40:11.204Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a017fdd61313781045889ec"),  "device_id" : "12222",   "value" : "23233", "pubtime" : ISODate("2017-11-07T09:41:49.452Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a017ff561313781045889ed"),  "device_id" : "1232213",   "value" : "23233", "pubtime" : ISODate("2017-11-07T09:42:13.658Z") }
```

I want to distinct it by `"device_id"` AND sort it by `"pubtime"`.

I know that Golang could use pipe to do it. But I don't know how to do it. What I tried:

```
o1 := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"device_id": "$device_id"}}

o2 := bson.M{"pubtime": bson.M{"$last": "$pubtime"}}
o3 := bson.M{"$group": []bson.M{o1, o2}}
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{o3})
var result = []bson.M{}
_ = pipe.All(&result)
fmt.Println(result)
```

The result is empty.

It is ok in MongoDB:

```
db.collections.aggregate({"$group":
                        {"_id":{"device_id":"$device_id"},
                        "pubtime":{"$last": "$pubtime"} ,
                       "value":{"$last": "$value"} ,
                        }});
```

Comment: <pre>o1 := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"device_id": "$device_id"}}

o2 := bson.M{"pubtime": bson.M{"$last": "$pubtime"}}
o3 := bson.M{"$group": []bson.M{o1, o2}} pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{o3})
var result []bson.M{}
_ = pipe.All(&result)
fmt.Println(result)</pre> It was get empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the errors, that's your main problem. `Pipe.All()` returns an error which you gracefully discard. Don't do that.

```
var result = []bson.M{}
err := pipe.All(&result)
fmt.Println(result, err)
```

This will print:

```
[] a group's fields must be specified in an object
```

The error says it all. The value of `$group` must be e.g. a `bson.M` value, and not a slice of `bson.M`:

```
o3 := bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
    "_id":     bson.M{"device_id": "$device_id"},
    "pubtime": bson.M{"$last": "$pubtime"},
}}
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{o3})
var result = []bson.M{}
err := pipe.All(&result)
fmt.Println(result, err)
```

Now the output will be:

`[map[_id:map[device_id:12222] pubtime:2017-11-07 10:41:49.452 +0100 CET] map[_id:map[device_id:1111] pubtime:2017-11-07 10:40:11.204 +0100 CET] map[_id:map[device_id:1232213] pubtime:2017-11-07 10:42:13.658 +0100 CET]] <nil>`

So it works.

And to make the results sorted by `pubtime`, use `$sort`. Here's the final code:

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id":     bson.M{"device_id": "$device_id"},
            "pubtime": bson.M{"$last": "$pubtime"},
        },
    },
    {"$sort": bson.M{"pubtime": 1}},
})
var result = []bson.M{}
err := pipe.All(&result)
fmt.Println(result, err)
```

If you want the results sorted in descending order, then use:

```
{"$sort": bson.M{"pubtime": -1}}
```

Also note that when grouping, if the group `_id` is a single field, you don't need to wrap it into an object, you can simply use `$device_id` as the group id:

```
"$group": bson.M{
    "_id":     "$device_id",
    "pubtime": bson.M{"$last": "$pubtime"},
},
```

Comment: Thx a lot!Thx a lot!Thx a lot!Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) in mongodb aggregation pipeline

Mongodb shell query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:{device_id:"$device_id"}, pubtime:{$first:"$pubtime"}}}
]);
```

The result which we get after executing the above query in mongo shell

```
{ "_id" : { "device_id" : "12222" }, "pubtime" : ISODate("2017-11-07T09:41:49.452Z") }
{ "_id" : { "device_id" : "1111" }, "pubtime" : ISODate("2017-11-07T09:40:11.204Z") }
{ "_id" : { "device_id" : "1232213" }, "pubtime" : ISODate("2017-11-07T09:37:37.006Z") }
```

Comment: Sorry，I want to know how to do in Golang.

Comment: My Mongodb shell is ok.